# changing background on wordpress posts page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm trying to change the background on **just** the posts page on my wordpress website - http://adamcwdev.marcuscramer.co.uk/journal/

so far I've managed to change the background on all the pages using the following code:

```
background-image: url("http://adamcwdev.marcuscramer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/G91B40882.jpg");
min-height: 500px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #ffffff;
```

However I can't change the specific post page alone. The page id is post=10

Answer (score 1):

As Huelfe stated above or below you can target blog pages by using:

```
body.blog
```

you can also target single post or category pages using:

```
body.single-post
body.category
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You have `blog` defined as a class of your body. Use it:

```
body.blog #YOURELEMENT {
  background-image: url("http://adamcwdev.marcuscramer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/G91B40882.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```